# Use of unassigned local variable 'fileData'?

Tags: c#

The compiler is reading Error: Use of unassigned local variable 'fileData'.

I have searched but none of the things I have tried solved my problem.

```
 private ScrPrnData ParseTemperatureFileLine(string sLine)
    {
        char[] delimiter = { '\t' };
        string[] elements = sLine.Split(delimiter, 200);

        ScrPrnData fileData; 

        fileData.dTempZone1 = double.Parse(elements[0].Trim());
        fileData.dTempZone2 = double.Parse(elements[1].Trim());
        fileData.dTempZone3 = double.Parse(elements[2].Trim());
        fileData.dTempZone4 = double.Parse(elements[3].Trim());

        return fileData;
    }
```

Comment: Which line does it show as having the error?

Comment: `ScrPrnData fileData = new ScrPrnData();` ?

Answer (score 2):

```cs
private ScrPrnData ParseTemperatureFileLine(string sLine)
{
    ...
    ScrPrnData fileData = new ScrPrnData(); 
    ...
}
```

Comment: @TheRealDK - That's the issue with the sample you've posted. Is there code left out?

Comment: The issue is on 'return fileData;' Compiler says unassigned local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an actual object of that type:

```
ScrPrnData fileData = new ScrPrnData();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're never initializing `fileData` and compiler is saving you the obvious NullReferenceException at runtime.

```
ScrPrnData fileData; // <- need to initialize this here.

// fileData will always be null here and throw an Exception
// the compiler knows this and is saving you the headache
fileData.dTempZone1 = double.Parse(elements[0].Trim());
```

Comment: Believe so that you have to explain how to solve it, because you are telling him the error, just ScrPrnData fileData = new ScrPrnData() :D

Comment: It all depends on what ScrPrnData is.  If it's an abstract class or interface, for example, then "new ScrPrnData()" won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're using fileData without initializing it with some value.  Try:

```
ScrPrnData fileData = new ScrPrnData();
```

or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate it.

```
 ScrPrnData fileData;  = new ScrPrnData ();
```